# Enzyme not passing context to rendered component on Travis

Tags: reactjs, react-router, travis-ci, enzyme

I have a peculiar situation that has been occurring. I have been testing my React application with Mocha, Enzyme, Chai, and nyc.

Locally on my machine everything works perfectly of my 6 tests that I have all 6 pass. 2 of those tests are tests that call mount from enzyme:

```
it('Should contain my name in the text', () => {
    const context = { router: { } };
    const footer = mount(<Footer />, context);
    console.log(footer);
    expect(footer.text()).to.contain('Myname');
  });
  it('Should contain a link to the copyright page', () => {
    const footer = mount(<Footer />);
    expect(footer.find('a').prop('href')).to.equal('/Copyright');
  });
```

On my local machine these run fine. When my tests get run on Travis-ci, these two tests fail for the following reason:

```
Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
in Link (created by Unknown)
in footer (created by Unknown)
in Unknown (created by Unknown)
in Unknown
```

I am very perplexed as to why this is not failing on my local machine if this is the case. I would love any help that I could get to try to figure this out.

The version of software I am currently using:

```
"chai": "^3.5.0",
"enzyme": "^2.6.0",
"mocha": "^3.1.0",
"react-dom": "15.4.0",
"react": "15.4.0",
"react-router": "next" #this is version v4
```

Comment: I would try adding a shrinkwrap or package lock file to your project, just to make sure you're not having an issue with dependencies updating to versions they're not supposed to (but valid according to your semver rules).